# tex4ht - how to properly number equations (MathJax)

Tags: tex4ht

I'm using `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` in my LaTeX preambule and I'd like that the same numbering applies in resulting HTML when compiled using tex4ht.

My latex code block in Section 2 is:

```latex
This is test of equation array
\begin{eqnarray}
x = a+1  \nonumber\\ 
y = b+1 \label{eq:myarray}
\end{eqnarray}
and here I reference it \eqref{eq:myarray}
```

Which gives me in PDF:
[image]

If I run `make4ht --shell-escape article.tex "mathjax"` I get in the HTML:
[image]
=> so obviously the reference is bad (??).

If I make a config `test.cfg` with

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\eqref[1]{\NoFonts\HChar{92}eqref\{\detokenize{#1}\}\EndNoFonts}
\EndPreamble
```

and I run `make4ht --shell-escape article.tex "mathjax" --config test` I get:
[image]
This fixes the problem with the "??" but doesn't give (2.1).

If I do `make4ht --shell-escape article.tex "mathml,mathjax"` I get
[image]
This indeed generates (2.1) but the formula label is in a strange position. And I prefer NOT to use mathml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure MathJax to display equation numbers in this style. I've found [this help page](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/tagformat.html#tex-tagformat) which describes a plugin that should do that, and thanks to the examples from [this issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2427), I was able to came with a solution.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
This is test of equation array
\begin{eqnarray}
x = a+1  \nonumber\\ 
y = b+1 \label{eq:myarray}
\end{eqnarray}
and here I reference it $\eqref{eq:myarray}$

\section{Second}


\begin{eqnarray}
x = a+1  \nonumber\\ 
y = b+1 \label{eq:myarray2}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

The configuration file can look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\Configure{MathJaxConfig}{{}}
\Configure{AddJs}{mathjaxconfig.js}
\Configure{section}{}{\HCode{<span style="display: hidden">\detokenize{\(\nextSection\)}</span>}}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar
    \HCode{<h3 class="sectionHead">}\TitleMark\space\HtmlParOff}
   {\HCode{</h3>}\HtmlParOn \ShowPar\par}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It does few things:

- it disables the default TeX4ht configuration for MathJax
- it loads the `mathjaxconfig.js` file, which is shown below
- it configures the `\section` command to put the `\nextSection` at the end of each section. It updates the counter that MathJax uses for the section number

Because the JavaScript code is too complex to be included in the config file, I had to put it to a standalone file, `mathjaxconfig.js`:

```javascript
MathJax ={
loader: {load: ['[tex]/tagFormat']},
  section: 1,
  tex: {
    tags: 'ams',
    packages: {'[+]': ['tagFormat', 'sections']},
    tagformat: {
      number: (n) => MathJax.config.section + '.' + n,
      id: (n) => 'eqn-id-' + n
    }
  },
  startup: {
    ready() {
      const Configuration = MathJax._.input.tex.Configuration.Configuration;
      const CommandMap = MathJax._.input.tex.SymbolMap.CommandMap;
      new CommandMap('sections', {
        nextSection: 'NextSection'
      }, {
        NextSection(parser, name) {
          MathJax.config.section++;
          parser.tags.counter = parser.tags.allCounter = 0;
        }
      });
      Configuration.create(
        'sections', {handler: {macro: ['sections']}}
      );
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
      MathJax.startup.input[0].preFilters.add(({math}) => {
        if (math.inputData.recompile) MathJax.config.section = math.inputData.recompile.section;
      });
      MathJax.startup.input[0].postFilters.add(({math}) => {
        if (math.inputData.recompile) math.inputData.recompile.section = MathJax.config.section;
      });
   }
  }
}
```

With these changes, I get this result for the MWE:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! _Extremely_ useful! 100% sure this will be a frequently searched answer.

Comment: @user2743931 thanks for your kind words. I hope it will be useful. I tried to get this to work in the past, but only now I've found the correct information how to get it to work in MathJax. To add TeX4ht support was then relatively easy.